# How to keep UITableView's datasource ordered in response to user moving rows around?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a UITableView and one of its sections is managed by a NSFetchedResultsController. It fetches core data objects and keep them sorted by the "order" attribute:

1. object with order 1
2. object with order 2
3. object with order 3

The requirement that I'm facing is that the user can move rows around. After move:

1. object with order 2
2. object with order 1
3. object with order 3

**What do I need to do to ensure that the managed objects in core data reflect changes in order resulting from user moving table view rows around?**  When I'm working with GMGridView, there's a callback that exchanges two objects. In such case, changing their order works, but I do not see such function for a UITableView.

Would I need to manually change the order attribute for all objects that exist below the moved row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
    - (NSIndexPath *)            tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
                       toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

Plus re-ordering your data-source, by exchanging the objects order.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store an association between the fetched object and the 'row order'.  You order the rows based on row order; the row order defaults to your 'order' attribute.  When the user moves a row, you update the 'row order' as well.

You can maintain the association either in the CoreData object itself (add another attribute) or by mapping the fetched object to its row order (in `NSUserDefaults` or in just a `NSDictionary`).

Answer (score 1):

Moving rows around does not just affect the order attribute of itself but all the rows behind it. A work around I have found is to copy the fetch request objects to an nsmutablearray then moving the object within this array. Then running a for loop and updating the order attribute in each object then saving the managed object context. Then reload the uitableview. This seems like a lot of work but currently moving objects in a fetch request is not automatic like insert and delete. I hope this helps!