# Moving rows on tableview using core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

in an iOS app I have a tableview which shows core data records. I don't know how to  implement the canMoveRowAtIndexPath method. The core data entity name is ToDoPro, and I have created an attribute called displayOrder which should retain the display order in the table. My question is, taking into account the current code, what should I include in the canMoveRowAtIndexPath method to store the last display order for future views of the table.
Here is current code:

```
#import "TodayListViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ToDoPro.h"

@interface TodayListViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray* fetchedRecordsArray;
@end

@implementation TodayListViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.fetchedRecordsArray = [appDelegate getAllToDoRecords];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.fetchedRecordsArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    ToDoPro* todopro = [self.fetchedRecordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",todopro.todotext];

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

Comment: [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132740/how-to-keep-uitableviews-datasource-ordered-in-response-to-user-moving-rows-aro)

Comment: You just dumped the boilerplate code. Please show what you tried.

Comment: I have put following code inside the moveRowAtIndexPath: arrayCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.fetchedRecordsArray];
    int i = 0;
    for (NSManagedObject *newList in arrayCopy)
    {
        [newList setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
    }

Comment: But now I need to store the new displayOrder value onto the real core data entity, not to the NSMutableArray....

Comment: Please keep in mind, that I am using a NSArray to display the records on the tableview. The fetchresultscontroller is stored in a method in the AppDelegate.m file.